# Testing ARGV options with rspec. How to expect a method to call a method from another module

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am building a CLI in Ruby and I am using ARGV to pass options and arguments in the command line. I have a call method that is triggered when the CLI is executed.
The call method is as follows:

```
module Eltiempo
  class CLI
    def call
      help_menu if ARGV.count.zero?
      case ARGV[0]
      when '-today'
        raise NoCityError if ARGV[1].nil?

        Eltiempo.today(ARGV[1])
      when '-av_min'
        raise NoCityError if ARGV[1].nil?

        Eltiempo.av_min(ARGV[1])
      when '-av_max'
        raise NoCityError if ARGV[1].nil?

        Eltiempo.av_max(ARGV[1])
      when '-h'
        help_menu
      end
    end
```

When doing the test with rspec for the first case option (-today) I have written the following code:

```
RSpec.describe Eltiempo do
  describe '#call' do
    context 'given -today' do
      let(:ARGV) { ['-today', 'Barcelona'] }
      it 'calls function to return today\'s weather' do
        expect(Eltiempo::CLI.new.call).to receive(Eltiempo.today).with(ARGV[1])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However, when running rspec it is not passing the test and it says:

```
Failure/Error:
       def self.today(city_name)
         max = max_today(city_name)
         min = min_today(city_name)
         puts "Weather today in #{city_name.capitalize}:
           - Maximum: #{max}°C
           - Minimum: #{min}°C"
       end
     
     ArgumentError:
       wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)
```

It is trying to call the method `self.today(city_name)` in Eltiempo module and to run in without the city_name argument, however, I do not want it to run the method I just want to check that when the option and argument `-today Barcelona` is run, it calls `Eltiempo.today(ARGV[1])`.

Why is it running `self.today(city_name)`?

Answer (score 1):

The method call is coming from inside the house!

```
expect(Eltiempo::CLI.new.call).to receive(Eltiempo.today).with(ARGV[1])
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

That is just what it looks like, a call to `Eltiempo.today` with no arguments.

Setting up an expectation says you expect a particular object to receive a certain method. This object in this case is the class `Eltiempo`. The method is passed *by name* as a Symbol. After the expectation that `today` will be called on `Eltiempo` is set up, then you run the code which is expected to call `Eltiempo.today`

```
expect(Eltiempo).to receive(:today).with(ARGV[1])
Eltiempo::CLI.new.call
```

RSpec has replaced the method `today` on `Eltiempo` with one that records whether it's been called and returns nothing.